# jquery if css height > Xpx do this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to trigger a function with jquery once a CSS element reaches a certain height?

I imagine an example would look something like:

```
function(){
if( $("#bar").css('height') > '20px') {
$("#mydiv").show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<b style="display:none" id="mydiv">Hello!</b>
```

Can't seem to find a way to successfully make it work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ptkqajv/1/

Comment: remove `px` unit. and use this: `if($("#bar").height() > 20){ $("#mydiv").show(); }`

Comment: are you resizing the element? if yes then put this `if($('#bar')..` code in that event.

Comment: How does the element change its height ?

Comment: I'll make a fiddle for an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: function advanceRound() {
    current_round++;
     if($("#fill").height() > 60){ $("#mydiv").show(); }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your check in the click-function, so it gets executed when the height is changing:

```
$('h1').on("click", function() {
    advanceRound();
    render();
    if($("#fill").height() > 60){ 
        $("#mydiv").show(); 
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh0pjpLy/)**

Alternativly you cann add the check in your function `renderBar()`.

Comment: You're all correct but I can only choose 1 answer, I chose this one because it's the one that I worked from. Thanks to everyone.